# I have a MySQL database whereI am trying to retrieve JSON data that stores urls but the results keep coming back empty

Tags: mysql, json, escaping

The data in the column looks like the below:

```
{
"activity": {
    "token": "e7b64be4-74d4-7a6d-a74b-xxxxxxx",
    "route": "http://example.com/enroll/confirmation",
    "url_parameters": {
        "Success": "True",
        "ContractNumber": "003992314W",
        "Barcode": "1908Y10Z",
        "price": "8.99"
    },
    "server_info": {
        "cookie": [
            "_ga=xxxx; _fbp=xxx; _hjid=xxx; XDEBUG_SESSION=XDEBUG_ECLIPSE;"
        ],
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": [
            "1"
        ],
    },
    "campaign": "Unknown/None",
    "ip": "192.168.10.1",
    "entity": "App\\Models\\User",
    "entity_id": "1d9f3066-13ce-4659-b10d-xxxxx",
},
"time": "2021-05-21 20:15:02"
```

}

```
My code that I am using is below: 
SELECT *
FROM websote.stored_events
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(event_properties, '$.route') = 'http://example.com/enroll/confirmation'
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 500;
```

The code works on the other the json values just not the url ones.  I've tried escaping the values in MySQL like the below:

```
SELECT *
    FROM websote.stored_events
    WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(event_properties, '$.route') = 'http:///example.com//enroll//confirmation'
    ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 500;
```

But still no luck. Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: *I've tried escaping* - escaping uses \ not /. No need to escape /

Answer (score 1):

Your example data isn't valid JSON. You can't have a comma after the last element in an object or array:

```
    "entity_id": "1d9f3066-13ce-4659-b10d-xxxxx",
},
                                                ^ here
```

If I remove that and other similar cases, I can test your data inserts into a JSON column and I can extract the object element you described:

```
mysql> select json_extract(event_properties, '$.activity.route') as route from stored_events;
+------------------------------------------+
| route                                    |
+------------------------------------------+
| "http://example.com/enroll/confirmation" |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Note the value is returned with double-quotes. This is because it's returned as a JSON document, a scalar string. If you want the raw value, you have to unquote it:

```
mysql> select json_unquote(json_extract(event_properties, '$.activity.route')) as route from stored_events;
+----------------------------------------+
| route                                  |
+----------------------------------------+
| http://example.com/enroll/confirmation |
+----------------------------------------+
```

If you want to search for that value, you would have to do a similar expression:

```
select * from stored_events 
where json_unquote(json_extract(event_properties, '$.activity.route')) 
  = 'http://example.com/enroll/confirmation'
```

Searching based on object properties stored in JSON has disadvantages.

- It requires complex expressions that force you (and anyone else you needs to maintain your code) to learn a lot of details about how JSON works.
- It cannot be optimized with an index. This query will run a table-scan. You can add virtual columns with indexes, but that adds to complexity and if you need to ALTER TABLE to add virtual columns, it misses the point of JSON to store semi-structured data.

The bottom line is that if you find yourself using JSON functions in the WHERE clause of a query, it's a sign that you should be storing the column you want to search as a normal column, not as part of a JSON document.

Then you can write code that is easy to read, easy for your colleagues to maintain, and can be optimized easily with indexes:

```
SELECT * FROM stored_events 
WHERE route = 'http://example.com/enroll/confirmation';
```

You can still store other properties in the JSON document, but the ones you want to be searchable should be stored in normal columns.

You might like to view my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-use-json-in-mysql-wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Route is a nested property; I would have expected the path to be

```
JSON_EXTRACT(event_properties, '$.activity.route')
```

Comment: Other json names on the same level work without having 'activity' in it

Comment: It's the escaping that isn't working for whatever reason. JSON_EXTRACT(event_properties, '$.token') works

Comment: If you `select JSON_EXTRACT(event_properties, '$.route') from website.stored_events`, what do you see?

Comment: *'$.token' works* - are you sure? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6a20febb61eec136a5c285f8a76fcd6b